# XOR problem with neural network, cost function

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I am having a problem understanding the cost function in a neural network. I have read many books and blog posts, but all of them describe that point in neural networks is to minimize the cost function (like sum squared error):

[image]

I tried to look at code for solving a problem with a multi layer neural network and back propagation. My question is: where in the code can I find the cost function? How can I plot the error surface?

```
import numpy as np
X_XOR = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,1],[1,1,1]])
y_truth = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
def sigmoid_der(output):
    return output * (1 - output)

np.random.seed(1)
syn_0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn_1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1

for i in range(60000):
    layer_1 = sigmoid(X_XOR.dot(syn_0))
    layer_2 = sigmoid(layer_1.dot(syn_1))
    error = 0.5 * ((layer_2 - y_truth) ** 2)
    layer_2_delta = error * sigmoid_der(layer_2)
    layer_1_error = layer_2_delta.dot(syn_1.T)
    layer_1_delta = layer_1_error * sigmoid_der(layer_1)
    syn_1 -= layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
    syn_0 -= X_XOR.T.dot(layer_1_delta)
    if i % 10000 == 1:
        print(layer_2)

print(layer_2)
```

Comment: @JahKnows can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost function can be found in the **delta rule**, meaning the way you calculate your deltas. This delta is nothing more than the **derivative of your error function after the weights**: $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_{ij}}$. So, if you are just interested in where the cost is encoded, this is the answer you are looking for.

If you, on the other hand want to know **why** this formula works, I can suggest you to read the [derivation on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule). The maths behind it is quite uncomplicated, you only compute the derivative in each layer and propagate this derivative through the layers. This is, by the way, how **backpropagation** got its name.

Comment: Ok, It possible to plot error surface for my solution?

Comment: You can simply plot your error surface by plotting the variable "error" in each step of your algorithm, if that is what you desire.

Comment: not exactly, I want to plot 3d error surface

Comment: Can you please specify what you want to plot. I was thinking about the iterations on the x axis and the error on the y axis.

Comment: My neural network has 2 layer. I was thinking about 3d error surface like this https://imgur.com/60Evv6U